# How to configure Azure Functions to connect to VM behind an NSG

Tags: azure-functions, azure-virtual-network, azure-nsg

I have a DB hosted on a VM and a NSG setup around the VM. Not I need azure functions to access the VM.

How would I configure NSG to allow Azure Functions to access the VM

Comment: You need to whitelist the Outbound IP addresses of the function app in NSG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DixitArora-MSFT's comment mentioned, you could whitelist [the function App outbound IP address.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ip-addresses#find-outbound-ip-addresses) Since some actions may change the IP address such as changing your App Service plan pricing tier, you need to whitelist a set of `possibleOutboundIpAddresses`. Another option is to whitelist the function apps' data center (Azure region). You can download a JSON file that [lists IP addresses for all Azure data centers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519).

If you want to whitelist only with a known IP address, seems that the only way is to use a third-party proxy service or a different fundamental technology. Refer to [this](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/464#issuecomment-328329670).

Furthermore, since your DB is hosted on Azure VM, I think you also could consider [integrating a function app with an Azure virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-vnet) for securely accessing the VM in a private network.